# How to send object from Flutter to Android?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, serialization, flutter-method-channel

I have class in Flutter:

```
class Foo {
  String id;
  int power;

  Foo (this.id, this.power);

  Map toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'power': power
  };
}
```

I've created a instance of this object and pass it to Android via MethodChannel as a `String`:

```
_myChannel.invokeMethod('custom_event', {
      'foo': foo.toJson().toString(),
});
```

In Android I retrive that string and want to convert to Foo object on Android side so:

```
val fooString = call.method.argument<String>("foo")
//output: {id: my_id, power: 23}

val response = fooString?.let { Response(it) }
//output {"id":"my_id","power":"23"}
```

Helper class:

```
class Response(json: String) : JSONObject(json) {
        val data = this.optJSONArray(null)
            ?.let { 0.until(it.length()).map { i -> it.optJSONObject(i) } } // returns an array of JSONObject
            ?.map { FooJson(it.toString()) } // transforms each JSONObject of the array into Foo
    }

    class FooJson(json: String) : JSONObject(json) {
        val id: String = this.optString("id")
        val power: String = this.optInt("power")
    }
```

How I can convert response to my Kotlin's class?

Comment: Could you specify a problem please? Because you have Response class that parse the JSON. But it looks weird because you trying parse the array instead of object

Comment: Yeah, I want to pass list of objects from Flutter to Android as a String and then convert string to list of objects again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Foo` just contains a string and an integer, both of which are supported by the default message codec, it would make sense to simply pass those two values in a map. (In fact, you already have a method that creates that map, `toJson`, though a better name might be `toMap`.)

Don't then call `toString` on that map; instead use:

```
_myChannel.invokeMethod('custom_event', foo.toMap());
```

You are now invoking the method and passing the map. At the native end, you are going to look for the members using their map keys (i.e. `id` and `power`) using `.argument<T>` as you've tried, as follows:

```
val id = call.method.argument<String>("id");
```

You could, of course, then create a POJO that wraps an object around those two values, if really necessary.

For more complex messages, consider [Pigeon](https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon). If you really want to use JSON as your method of serialization, look at the existing JSON message codec.

Comment: I want to handle passing list of Foo objects so I thought parsing object to string and then to json is good idea. I don't want to use any external library to handle it.

Comment: It's not a particularly good idea, since the default codec can already do lists, maps, strings, etc etc. Why re-invent the wheel? If you want to pass a list of Foos, turn each Foo to a map, put them in a list and pass the list to invoke method. At the Java end you'll get an ArrayList of HashMaps - easy to traverse.

Comment: What should i use if my Foo class has id, power and 2 more variables?

Comment: The same map with two extra key/values, for example `{.... 'isAlive': isAlive, 'logPower': logPower}` - showing an example of being able to pass a boolean and double straight through.